# addEventListener not working for toggle button

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

I'm working on a feature in **Flask** to switch between a dark and light theme. I'm using Flask, CSS and Javascript in seperate files. When the toggle button is clicked the css stylesheet is not changed.

```
application
├── static
│   ├── css
│   |   ├── base-theme.css
│   |   ├── dark-theme.css
│   └── js
│       ├── switch_themes.js
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
```

**base.html**

```
!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Application</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Application">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base-theme.css') }}" id="switch_theme">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/switch_themes.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <table class="topnav_right">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="topnav_theme">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a class="theme" href="/">THEME</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="topnav_mode">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <button id="btn-toggle">
                                                <label class="switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                                    <span class="slider"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                </tr>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

**switch_themes.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    const toggle = document.getElementById("btn-toggle");
    const theme = document.getElementById("switch_theme");

    toggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "/static/css/base-theme.css") {
            theme.href = "/static/css/dark-theme.css";
        } else {
            theme.href = "/static/css/base-theme.css";
        }
    });
}
```

The application works without errors (also no errors in the console of the browser) however the theme is not switched when the toggle button (btn-toggle) is clicked.

Best Regards,

Maarten

Comment: Did you check if clicking on the button is changing the `href` value of the `link` tag?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. The value for href is somehow blinking but not changing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

It was actually working, however the `<button>` was redundant and the area to click on for the button was too small due to the `<label>` and `<span>` tags. I have changed the code below and now it works:

```
<td>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="btn-toggle">
        <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
</td>
```